# Android Studio Se puede poner el LogCat en colores?

Tags: android-studio

¿Es posible poner el monitor LogCat de Android Studio de diferente color, para diferenciar, Warnings, Error,Debug, Info, Verbose y Asserts?

Algo parecido a [Pid Cat](https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usted puede hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

`File` >> `Settings` > `Editor` > `Color & Fonts` > `Andorid Logcat`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta captura es sobre `Android Studio 1.5.1`, para otras versiones no puede consultarlo ahora mismo pero si usted cuenta con otra version, puede tratar de buscar por `Preferences/Settings` > `Editor` o `File` >> `Settings`.

Como puede ver aparte de los predefinidos por el `Scheme`, puede observar que aparecen `Assert`, `Debug`, `Error`, `Info`, `Verbose`, `Warning` y al lado `Foreground` y demas caracteristicas a editar, segun cambia de uno a otro vera las caracteristicas que se aplican a cada uno pudiendo modificarlas .

Comment: Puedes complementar la solución añadiendo, Para tema Darcula: Debug : 6897BB Info : 6A8759 Warning : BBB529 Error : FF6B68 Assert : 9876AA